# React Native Android app asking to call deprecated 'FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize'

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-android-sdk

React-Native v. 0.47.2
react-native-fbsdk v. 0.6.0/0.6.1

I need to get Facebook login setup for an app. It's been a real struggle on Android. When you install via the Facebook docs ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current) then through the quickstart) and run your program this is the first error that pops up:

```
/Users/Parthenon/Desktop/go3/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

As per this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14670) I've tried explicitly stating the version in react-native-fbsdk gradle at:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
```

With anything but version `4.22.1` I get the above error. For version `4.22.1` the project builds which is awesome but then it throws the error:

```
The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
```

This is really strange because `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` was deprecated well before `4.22`. If I call that method the app runs then crashes. But it crashes with no error log.

What's going on here or what should I try next?

Comment: did you found a workaround?

Comment: @ezdookie This is a confirmed bug. I followed a bug report with them over a week ago. The best thread to follow on this is here... https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14670#issuecomment-328103530

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue and I realize that I have to complete all steps to configure the native facebook sdk for android. Its mean you need to have a facebook account for this work.
What you need to do next is:

1. In your project open `yourapp/android/build.gradle`
2. Add the Maven Central Repository to build.gradle before dependencies:

   `repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }`
3. Add `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`to your `build.gradle` dependencies
4. Build project
5. Open your strings.xml file, for example: `/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml.`and add `<string name="facebook_app_id">xxxxxxxx</string>`
6. Open your AndroidManifest.xml and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
7. Add meta to application element `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`
8. Generate a development key hash

You can see detail in quick start of developer facebook page (developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/)